# Show that the set of LES-solutions form a sub-vector space of $\mathbb{R^n}$ exactly when $b_i = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, systems-of-equations

> The linear system of equations is given:
>   \begin{align}
> a_{11}x_1+\dots& +a_{1n}x_n=b_1\\
> &\vdots\\
> a_{m1}x_1+\dots&+a_{mn}x_n=b_m
> \end{align}
>   Show that the set of the given linear equation system solutions form a sub-vector space of $\mathbb{R^n}$ exactly when $b_i = 0, \;\forall1\leq i \leq m$

"$\leftarrow$" Let $U$ be the solution set of the system of equations and $\forall b_i=0$. Then $0\in U\neq\emptyset$ and it immediately applies that if $u,v\in U: u+v=0+0\iff0\in U$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{K},\;u\in U: \lambda u = 0\cdot u = 0\in U$ and therefore $U$ is a sub-vector space of $\mathbb{R}^n$

"$\rightarrow$" How to go on? Should I assume, that $\forall b_i\neq0$ and try to show, that the axioms of subspaces only hold for $b_i=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any vector subspace of $\mathbb R^{n}$ contains the zero vector $(0,0,...,0)$. So the equation must hold when each $x_i$ is $0$ which gives $b_i=0$ for all $i$.